# encontrar texto especifico dentro de array en Laravel

Tags: laravel

tengo el siguiente json

```
[{"pais":"COLOMBIA","pais_id":"6","observacion":""},{"pais":"ECUADOR","pais_id":"15","observacion":""}]
```

el cual convierto en array con `$arreglo = json_decode($request->id_paises);`

de tal manera que me queda

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#514
    +"pais": "COLOMBIA"
    +"pais_id": "6"
    +"observacion": ""
  }
  1 => {#515
    +"pais": "ECUADOR"
    +"pais_id": "15"
    +"observacion": ""
  }
]
```

y quiero que, al encontrar el nombre de un país específico, por ejemplo **COLOMBIA**, me ejecute un código, de lo contrario que no haga nada

estaba recorriendo el array con un foreach

```
            foreach($arreglo as $obj){
                    $pais = $obj->pais;
                    if ($pais == "COLOMBIA") {
                        echo "existe";
                    }else{
                        echo "no existe";
                    }
            }
```

pero como está recorriendo cada array, me imprime **existe** las veces que encuentra el texto, y sigue recorriendo imprimiendo **no existe** las veces que no encontró el texto

quisiera saber de qué manera, hago para que cuando encuentre el texto, imprima **existe** y detenga la ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

hice lo que me dijiste @Rodney y lo solucioné de la siguiente manera

```
            $arreglo = json_decode($request->id_paises);
            foreach($arreglo as $obj){
                    $pais = $obj->pais;
                    if ($pais == "COLOMBIA") {
                        $final = "COL";
                    }
            }
            if (isset($final)){
                $paises = new Paises;
                $paises->id_pais = 6;
                $paises->observacion = "";
                $paises->save();
            }else{
                echo "no existe";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma es pasar el array a una colección y aprovechar los [métodos disponibles](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) de las colecciones de Laravel.

Por ejemplo [`filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter)

Conviertes el array a una colección:

```
$collection = collect($array);
```

Aplica `filter()` sobre la colección para que retorne solamente los objetos cuya propiedad `pais` que coincida con el dato que le pasas:

```
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->pais == "COLOMBIA";
});
```

Aplica `count()` sobre el resultado de `filter()` para obtener un número (`0` cero si `filter()` no devolvió nada):

```
$filtered->count();
```

Si el resultado es `1` o más, es `verdadero`, si no, es `falso`:

```
echo $filtered->count()? 'SI existe': 'NO existe';
```

---

O todo el código:

```php
$array = json_decode('[{"pais":"COLOMBIA","pais_id":"6","observacion":""},{"pais":"ECUADOR","pais_id":"15","observacion":""}]');
$collection = collect($array);
$pais = "COLOMBIA";
$filtered_count = $collection->filter(function ($item, $key) use ($pais) {
    return $item->pais == $pais;
})->count();
echo $filtered_count? 'SI existe': 'NO existe';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo es necesario poner la palabra Break dentro de tu condición si existe para que finalice la ejecución del foreach como por ejemplo:

```
$mensaje= "";
foreach($arreglo as $obj){
                    $pais = $obj->pais;
                    if ($pais == "COLOMBIA") {
                        $mensaje = "existe";
                        break;
                    }else{
                        $mensaje = "no existe";
                    }
            }
echo $mensaje;
```

Comment: de la manera como me sugieres, si el texto está en el array de la posición 2, primero imprime **no existe**, y luego imprime **existe**

Comment: Entonces no es necesario tener el else con el echo "no existe' dentro del foreach. En vez de imprimir directamente dentro del foreach te recomiendo tener una variable fuera que se rellene con el texto que resulte de la busqueda.